# VSTO Add in for Office 365

Tags: excel, vsto, office365

I have a couple of Excel Add ins. If I move to Office 365, will these add ins be available ? Is there any development support(VSTO) for Office 365 ?

Answer (score 5):

I to have been curious about the answer to this, so went looking online.  From the following site, I'd say the answer is no.  It looks like developing for Office 365 is more along the lines of SharePoint development.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/donovanf/archive/2011/06/29/office-365-developer-guidance-and-resources.aspx

I have seen advertisements online for products such as this... http://www.ocxt.com/products that look like they could provide a possible solution for taking a vsto application to the web.

Answer (score 5):

I think things have moved on substantially since this question was asked. Microsoft seem to be fully committed to the Add-in approach with Office 2013 and the equivalent VSTO tooling available in VS2012.

The [Office Dev Center home page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/hh133430.aspx) has Office 2013 and VSTO Add-ins written all over it.

This [MSDN Blog Post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/officeapps/archive/2013/06/18/roadmap-for-apps-for-office-vsto-and-vba.aspx) also clearly shows Add-ins are still part of the strategy.

Until the full capabilities of Desktop MS Office are available in a browser, I can't see this situation changing.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean Office 365 installed on client PC then there is no issue with VSTO Add-ins. Our Chem4Word Add-in is using Office 2010 VSTO and happily works with 2010, 2013, 2016, 2019, O365.

If you mean Office 365 on-line then you have to redesign them using the Office 365 Javascript API