# VSTO Add-in Moving to Office 365

Tags: vba, sharepoint, vsto, excel-2010, office365

I work in an academic lab, and have been working on VSTO Add-In to Excel (primary to handle complex data analysis and generate reports, what I think is bread and butter for VSTO).  At the lab we have Office 2010 almost exclusively (universities are like that).  We are partnering with a drug company that is using Office 365.

They want to use the same Add-In I've been developing so we're all on the same page.  I've let our Tech Transfer office know in case there are any licensing issues, as I don't think that's my problem to figure out.

On the tech side of things, I've been trying to figure out if the Add-In will work with 365.  I built it in VS-2012 (academic version of professional) and it works well in Excel 2010 (though I keep adding to it).

I have read:

https://blogs.msdn.com/b/donovanf/archive/2011/06/29/office-365-developer-guidance-and-resources.aspx?Redirected=true

Which didn't make it sound hopeful, until I realized that if they get the premium edition it still includes a local install:

https://office.microsoft.com/en-us/business/office-online-microsoft-office-365-for-small-businesses-FX103037625.aspx

**So my question is if someone is using the 365 Premium Edition with a local instal, then will a VSTO built for 2010 still work?**  I may be able to answer this in a few days when I actual meet them in person (and thus try it out), but I'd like to know the answer ahead of time if possible.

If not, would the best solution be to back track into VBA (that seems backwards) or try to work with SharePoint (for the first time in my life).

Thanks.

Comment: Any thoughts?  I thought this was a good question, but maybe not.  I saw this question: [SO VSTO for 365](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7623290/vsto-add-in-for-office-365), but I don't know that it's really complete.  At least I don't know why a VSTO would not work with the Premium Edition.

Comment: We have a very similar scenario where I work.  

We wrote an add-in for Word 2003 that may needed ported to Office 365, however I am unsure where to begin.  

Originally it was requested that we port the add-in to Office/Word 2010 which was simple enough in Visual Studio 2013, however with Office365 it appears that we may need to use NAPA.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well hopefully, someone can save some worry by knowing that infact it will work with Premium addition of 365.  I was able to deploy the add-in without issue to their 365 local installs.  I don't think it will work with the lower versions, but I haven't had a chance to test that yet.

Comment: So are you saying if upgrade from Office 2016 Professional to Office 365 ProPlus(Microsoft 365 Apps for enterprise), the VSTO add-in will not work?